# EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime issue with leap Year in linq to entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, leap-year, entity-functions

When i have a leap year in my database (ex.: 29th Feb 2012). The EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime functions throws `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

My Code is as follows in my asp.net mvc (C#) application:

```
from u in _entities.tt_Users
let _start_date = u.Start_Date
let _startDate = _start_date.Day
let _startmonth = _start_date.Month
let _startyear = _start_date.Year
let _starthour = u.Start_Time.Value.Hours
let _startminutes = u.Start_Time.Value.Minutes
let _startseconds = u.Start_Time.Value.Seconds
let _startDateWithTime = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(_startyear, _startmonth, _startDate, _starthour, _startminutes, _startseconds)
let _startDateWithZeroTime = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(_startyear, _startmonth, _startDate, 0, 0, 0)
let _start_datetime = u.Is_Include_Time ? _startDateWithZeroTime : _startDateWithTime
let _end_date = u.End_Date
let _endDate = _end_date.Day
let _endmonth = _end_date.Month
let _endyear = _end_date.Year
let _endhour = u.End_Time.Value.Hours
let _endminutes = u.End_Time.Value.Minutes
let _endseconds = u.End_Time.Value.Seconds
let _endDateWithTime = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(_endyear, _endmonth, _endDate, _endhour, _endminutes, _endseconds)
let _endDateWithZeroTime = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(_endyear, _endmonth, _endDate, 0, 0, 0)
let _end_datetime = u.Is_Include_Time ? _endDateWithZeroTime : _endDateWithTime
let _cur_Start_date = u.Is_Include_Time ? _userStartDate : _gMTStartDate
let _cur_End_date = u.Is_Include_Time ? _userEndDate : _gMTEndDate
where u.User_Id == 1 && !u.Is_Deleted
&& _start_datetime >= _cur_Start_date && _end_datetime <= _cur_End_date
select new
{
  u.User_id,
  u.User_Name,
  u.Login_Name,
  u.Email_Address
};
```

Here _userStartDate, _userEndDate, _gMTStartDate and _gMTEndDate are parameters from my function.

If the column "Is_Include_Time" is true, then i have to include TimeSpan also from the table. But for the leap year Its throwing the error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem. I have some values in database rows that i need to convert to a datetime. I found out that I can use the following construct:

```
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            var counters = from counter in entities.Counter
                           let date = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", counter.DayOfMonth-1, SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month", counter.Month-1, SqlFunctions.DateAdd("year", counter.Year-1, startDate)))
                           where date >= dateFrom && date <= dateTo
                           orderby date
                           select new
                           {
                               Value = counter.CounterValue,
                               Date = date
                           };
```

I'm not sure of the performance impact, but it does work.

Best regards,
Tor-Odd

Answer (score 0):

try to use a declared variable outside the linq expression as I suggested [here](http://www.morgia.info/BlogEngine/post/2012/02/29/Entity-Framework-EntityFunctionsCreateDateTime-and-Leap-Year.aspx)

Comment: Its not going to work in my case, because i need to compare along with the date and time in the database. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I deal with

```
var minDate = Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00");
return source.Where(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(x.ReviewedDate, minDate) > 0).ToList();
```